# OneDrive API view.changes: How to get the most recent change token?

Tags: onedrive

The OneDrive API call [view.changes](http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm) will list all changes from the beginning of time and the last entry will have the most recent @changes.token.

However, if a OneDrive account has hundreds of thousands of changes then getting the most recent @changes.token requires caller to call [view.changes](http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm) hundreds of times.

So is there a way to quickly get the most recent @changes.token, for use with subsequent [view.changes](http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm)? For example, a call which does not return any entries just value of the  most recent @changes.token.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation at https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm

> *token* | string | The last token returned from the previous call to view.delta. **If omitted, view.delta returns the current state of the hierarchy**.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently get the most recent change token without completing an initial sync (which returns all of the current item metadata within the sync scope, but not every change that's happened in history).

Can you tell me what you're trying to build that makes you want only the latest change token?

Answer (score 0):

Infact you can get the latest token first before making the an api call to get latest changes:-

/drive/root/view.delta?token=latest

The above call will return the latest delta token value. You can include that value in your future calls like the following:-

/drive/items/{item-id}/view.changes?token={token}